# Kafka Kerberos Consumer api "Failed to find leader for Set(TOPICNAME,0)"

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm trying to configure security for Kafka using Kerberos.

And it's working fine by command prompt.

But facing problems when I'm trying it by java code.

Getting error as:

**Failed to find leader for Set([test,0], [test,1])**

**java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.formatAddress(Utils.java:312)**

Here is my code,

```
     final static String clientId = "SimpleConsumerDemoClient";
     public  final static String TOPIC = "test";
     ConsumerConnector consumerConnector;

      public static void main(String[] argv) throw 
       UnsupportedEncodingException {
         System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.realm", "EXAMPLE.COM");
        System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.kdc", "FQDN");
        System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.debug", "true");
        System.setProperty("sun.security.spnego.debug", "true");
       System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf","root/etc/krb5.conf");

        System.setProperty("javax.security.auth.useSubjectCredsOnly","false");
    Consumer helloKafkaConsumer = new Consumer();

    helloKafkaConsumer.start();
}

public Consumer(){
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("zookeeper.connect","DOMAIN:2181");
    properties.put("group.id","test-group");
    properties.put("security.protocol", "PLAINTEXTSASL");
    properties.put("auto.offset.reset","smallest");
    ConsumerConfig consumerConfig = new ConsumerConfig(properties);
    consumerConnector =  kafka.consumer.Consumer.createJavaConsumerConnector(consumerConfig);
}

@Override
public void run() {
    Map<String, Integer> topicCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    topicCountMap.put(TOPIC, new Integer(1));
    Map<String, List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>>> consumerMap = consumerConnector.createMessageStreams(topicCountMap);
    KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]> stream =  consumerMap.get(TOPIC).get(0);
    ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> it = stream.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        String str = new String(it.next().message(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        System.out.println(str+" The message consumed");
    }
}

private static void printMessages(ByteBufferMessageSet messageSet) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    for(MessageAndOffset messageAndOffset: messageSet) {
        ByteBuffer payload = messageAndOffset.message().payload();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[payload.limit()];
        payload.get(bytes);
        System.out.println(new String(bytes, "UTF-8"));
    }
}
```

}

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Might be an authentication error hidden behind several layers of `try - catch` obfuscation. Look into https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/secrets.html and activate the Kerberos debug trace accordingly. You maight see somtehing there (although it's cryptic, to say the less)

Comment: By the way, do you have a valid Kerberos ticket in the default ticket cache, so that your Java process can authenticate to ZK then Kafka? And did you set up a "Client" JAAS context *(Kafka library expects that exact name if I remember correctly)*

Comment: Ah, that one is not in the Gitbook but applies to Hive-HBase-Kafka clients that use raw JAAS config: `-Djava.security.debug=gssloginconfig,configfile,configparser,logincontext`

Comment: we have changes jaas conf file to use kafka keytab file...

Comment: but still its not working..